# JMeter BeanShell - Loop through values

Tags: loops, jmeter, beanshell

I try to use variables from an array as `Path` for `HTTP Request`. `Path` should be like this: `mypath/${act_value}`

```
String[] numbers = mylist.split(",");
String act_value;

for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    vars.put(numbers[i], act_value);
}
```

`mylist` is given as output of an extractor, comma separated string: `mylist=123,456,343,909`

`HTTP Request` state cannot access to this variable, I get error:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path

Comment: What value are you trying to send?

Comment: @user7294900 : It is working well, if I put there a value manually from `mylist`. `act_value` doesn't get a value in request.

Comment: You wanted something like vars.put("act_value" ,numbers[i]); ?

Comment: @user7294900 : I see `${act_value}` instead of value also in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Amend your code to look like:

   ```
   String myList = "123,456,343,909";
   String[] numbers = myList.split(",");
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       vars.put("number_" + i, numbers[i]);
   }
   ```
2. Add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) somewhere after this script and configure it as follows:

   - Input variable prefix: `number`
   - Output variable name: `act_value`
3. Put your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as a child of the ForEach Controller

   Your HTTP Request will be executed for each value in the `myList`

   [image: JMeter Iterate Variables]

---

Also consider switching to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), in the majority of cases valid Beanshell code will be valid Groovy code but performance will be much higher.

Comment: `mylist` is not defined in this state, I get it from an earlier extractor state, as output of it.

Comment: Dear `plaidshit`, I am not telepathic enough to guess how did you get your variable, if it comes from the extractor then change first line to be something like `String myList = vars.get("myList");`

Comment: @DmitriT - could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216384/foreach-controller-not-getting-triggered-in-jmeter