# ForEach controller not getting triggered in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter-5.0

My test sends a request and receives a `json` response which has an `array` in it. I want to iterate through each element of the array and send another request using the value in the array.

the overall structure looks like this

[image]

The response received for the first request is

```
    {"result":"success","additional-info":"{\"supported-tags\":[{\"course\":\"something\",\"subject\":\"something2\",\"topic\":\"something3\"},
...,
...]}"}
```

Using `JMESPath`, I first extract `additional-info` and store the value in `AdditionalInfoContainingGetSupportedTags`

[image]

Then I extract the array using `JMESPath` and store the value in `SupportedTags`

[image]

Then I use `ForEach` controller iterating over `SupportedTags`

[image]

I extract value in outging request like this  `"tags":["existing/${TagObject.course}-${TagObject.subject}-${TagObject.topic}"],`

But I don't think the `Foreach` gets started as I don't see anything in the tree

[image]

The `Debug Sampler` doesn't show anything as well (unless I am not using it correctly).

UPDATE - by increasing trace level of `jmeter` in 'log4J2.xml' at root level (from `INFO` to `TRACE`), I found this issue `2020-12-09 17:13:48,507 DEBUG o.a.j.c.ForeachController: ForEachTagController No entries found - null first entry: SupportedTags_1`. Still working on how to resolve it.

UPDATE 2 - I have done some more plumbing though to be honest, it isn't neat.
`ForEach` controller expects variables of type `SupportedTags_1`, `SupportedTags_2` etc. so I have created a `beanshell` script which exports such variables.

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

//prev.setSuccessful(false);
try {
    String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); //response as string
    log.info("received json string: "+jsonString);
    
    JsonObject responseAsJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString); //convert response string as json
    log.info("converted to object: "+responseAsJsonObject);
    
    String additionalInfoString = responseAsJsonObject.get("additional-info").asString(); //get additional info string from json object
    log.info("additional info as string: "+additionalInfoString);
    
    JsonObject additionalInfoJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(additionalInfoString); //convert additional info string to json
    log.info("additional info as object: "+additionalInfoJsonObject);
    
    JsonArray supportedTagsJsonObject = additionalInfoJsonObject.get("supported-tags").asArray(); 
    log.info("supported tags as array: "+supportedTagsJsonObject);
    log.info("array length "+supportedTagsJsonObject.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < supportedTagsJsonObject.size(); i++) {
        log.info("putting value "+"SupportedTags_"+(i+1)+"="+ supportedTagsJsonObject.get(i));
        vars.putObject("SupportedTags_"+(i+1), supportedTagsJsonObject.get(i));
    }
    

//  prev.setSuccessful(true);
} catch (Exception e){
    log.info("error in processing beanshell script: ", e);
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

I am now able to get the loop running but the issue is that I can't extract the values in subsequent requests because I am exporting a json object from the `beanshell` script but I can't access it like this in the request - `"tags":["existing/${TagObject.course}"]`. This gets printed literally.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a way to print the value of extracted `JMESPath` variables?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best approach but I solved the problem through `Beanshell` script. I extract the object in the script, convert it in the right format and export the right format

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

//prev.setSuccessful(false);
try {
    String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); //response as string
    log.info("received json string: "+jsonString);
    
    JsonObject responseAsJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString); //convert response string as json
    log.info("converted to object: "+responseAsJsonObject);
    
    String additionalInfoString = responseAsJsonObject.get("additional-info").asString(); //get additional info string from json object
    log.info("additional info as string: "+additionalInfoString);
    
    JsonObject additionalInfoJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(additionalInfoString); //convert additional info string to json
    log.info("additional info as object: "+additionalInfoJsonObject);
    
    JsonArray supportedTagsJsonObject = additionalInfoJsonObject.get("supported-tags").asArray(); 
    log.info("supported tags as array: "+supportedTagsJsonObject);
    log.info("array length "+supportedTagsJsonObject.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < supportedTagsJsonObject.size(); i++) {
        log.info("putting value SupportedTags_"+(i+1)+"="+ supportedTagsJsonObject.get(i));
        JsonObject convertedToTag = supportedTagsJsonObject.get(i).asObject();
        log.info("object is "+convertedToTag);
//      log.info("will put tag "+convertedToTag.getString("course","no course")+", "+convertedToTag.getString("subject","no subject")+", "+convertedToTag.getString("topic","no topic");
        String tag = convertedToTag.getString("course","no course")+"-"+convertedToTag.getString("subject","no subject")+"-"+convertedToTag.getString("topic","no topic");
        String courseCheck = convertedToTag.getString("course","no course");
        log.info("course is "+courseCheck);
        
    if(courseCheck.equals("coding")) {
      log.info("will put tag "+tag);
      vars.putObject("SupportedTags_"+(i+1), tag);          
    } else if (courseCheck.equals("no course")){
      log.info("error as course object doesn't exist in the json");
      throw Exception("error as course object doesn't exist in the json");
    }
    else {
      log.info("not putting tag as it doesn't start with coding"+tag);
    }
}
    

//  prev.setSuccessful(true);
} catch (Exception e){
    log.info("error in processing beanshell script: ", e);
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

USe in the request like this `"tags":["existing/${TagObject}"],`